# Terraform: User Data not rendered

Tags: terraform, user-data, cloud-init

Using `terraform` to run some user data upon instance creation:

```
  user_data = "${template_file.user_data.rendered}"
```

Here is the definition:

```
resource "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = "files/user_data.tpl"
  vars {
    docker_version = "17.12.1~ce-0~ubuntu"
  }
}
```

However, in the created instance, the user data just includes the above line:

```
sudo cat /var/lib/cloud/instances/i-05e8a76335472f27c/user-data.txt
files/user_data.tpl
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [template provider doc](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/index.html), the syntax should be:

```
data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = "${file(files/user_data.tpl)}"
  vars {
    docker_version = "17.12.1~ce-0~ubuntu"
  }
}

...
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  user_data = "${data.template_file.user_data.rendered}"
  ...
}
```

Comment: I hit an error: `A managed resource "user_data" "tpl" has not been declared in the root module.` Had to throw in an extra set of parenthesis: `template = "${file("user_data.tpl")}"`

Comment: Make sure you do not use hyphens in the filename also. Thanks for this post and the comment above!